# захват unique_ptr в лямбду

Tags: c++, stl, lambda

С++17

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

void invoke(std::function<void()> &&act) { act(); }

int main() {
    auto uniq = std::make_unique<int>(1);
    //не компилируется
    auto lambda = [cfg = std::move(uniq)]() mutable {};

    
    invoke(std::move(lambda));
    //так компилируется
    //lambda(); 
}
```

Получаю ошибку, т.к. std::function внутри начинает копироваться(судя по всему). Мне не ясно почему возникает копирование, а можно ли этого как-то избежать

gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0

> [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lambda_move_u.dir/main.cpp.o
> In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/functional:58:0,
> from /home/evgen/projects/lambda_move_u/main.cpp:2:
> /usr/include/c++/7/bits/std_function.h: In instantiation of ‘static void std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<_Functor>::_M_clone(std::_Any_data&, const std::_Any_data&, std::false_type) [with _Functor = main()::<lambda()>; std::false_type = std::integral_constant<bool, false>]’:
> /usr/include/c++/7/bits/std_function.h:227:16:   required from ‘static bool std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<_Functor>::_M_manager(std::_Any_data&, const std::_Any_data&, std::_Manager_operation) [with _Functor = main()::<lambda()>]’
> /usr/include/c++/7/bits/std_function.h:695:19:   required from ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor) [with _Functor = main()::<lambda()>;  = void;  = void; _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {}]’
> /home/evgen/projects/lambda_move_u/main.cpp:13:29:   required from here
> /usr/include/c++/7/bits/std_function.h:192:6: error: use of deleted function ‘main()::<lambda()>::(const main()::<lambda()>&)’
> new _Functor(*__source._M_access<_Functor*>());
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> /home/evgen/projects/lambda_move_u/main.cpp:10:41: note: ‘main()::<lambda()>::(const main()::<lambda()>&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
> auto lambda = cfg = std::move(uniq) mutable {};
> ^
> /home/evgen/projects/lambda_move_u/main.cpp:10:41: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete]’
> In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/memory:80:0,
> from /home/evgen/projects/lambda_move_u/main.cpp:3:
> /usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:383:7: note: declared here
> unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
> ^~~~~~~~~~

msvc19

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\functional(896): error C2280: 'main::<lambda_a0044794c0b7998ff7e3f3c20a6f8a39>::<lambda_a0044794c0b7998ff7e3f3c20a6f8a39>(const main::<lambda_a0044794c0b7998ff7e3f3c20a6f8a39> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
> E:\projects\lambda_test\main.cpp(10): note: see declaration of 'main::<lambda_a0044794c0b7998ff7e3f3c20a6f8a39>::<lambda_a0044794c0b7998ff7e3f3c20a6f8a39>'
> E:\projects\lambda_test\main.cpp(10): note: 'main::<lambda_a0044794c0b7998ff7e3f3c20a6f8a39>::<lambda_a0044794c0b7998ff7e3f3c20a6f8a39>(const main::<lambda_a0044794c0b7998ff7e3f3c20a6f8a39> &)': function was implicitly deleted because a data member invokes a deleted or inaccessible function 'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete> &)'
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\memory(3269): note: 'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete> &)': function was explicitly deleted
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\functional(901): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Func_impl_no_allocmain::<lambda_a0044794c0b7998ff7e3f3c20a6f8a39,_Ret>::_Func_impl_no_alloc<const _Callable&,0>(_Other)' being compiled
> with
> [
> _Ret=void,
> _Callable=main::<lambda_a0044794c0b7998ff7e3f3c20a6f8a39>,
> _Other=const main::<lambda_a0044794c0b7998ff7e3f3c20a6f8a39> &
> ]
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\functional(906): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Func_impl_no_allocmain::<lambda_a0044794c0b7998ff7e3f3c20a6f8a39,_Ret>::_Func_impl_no_alloc<const _Callable&,0>(_Other)' being compiled
> with
> [
> _Ret=void,
> _Callable=main::<lambda_a0044794c0b7998ff7e3f3c20a6f8a39>,
> _Other=const main::<lambda_a0044794c0b7998ff7e3f3c20a6f8a39> &
> ]
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\functional(901): note: while compiling class template member function 'std::_Func_base<_Ret> *std::_Func_impl_no_allocmain::<lambda_a0044794c0b7998ff7e3f3c20a6f8a39,_Ret>::_Copy(void *) const'
> with
> [
> _Ret=void
> ]
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\functional(813): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Func_impl_no_allocmain::<lambda_a0044794c0b7998ff7e3f3c20a6f8a39,_Ret>' being compiled
> with
> [
> _Ret=void
> ]
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\functional(1010): note: see reference to variable template 'const bool _Is_largestd::_Func_impl_no_alloc<<lambda_a0044794c0b7998ff7e3f3c20a6f8a39,void> >' being compiled
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\functional(1143): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret>::_Resetmain::<lambda_a0044794c0b7998ff7e3f3c20a6f8a39>(_Fx &&)' being compiled
> with
> [
> _Ret=void,
> _Fx=main::<lambda_a0044794c0b7998ff7e3f3c20a6f8a39>
> ]
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\functional(1143): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret>::_Resetmain::<lambda_a0044794c0b7998ff7e3f3c20a6f8a39>(_Fx &&)' being compiled
> with
> [
> _Ret=void,
> _Fx=main::<lambda_a0044794c0b7998ff7e3f3c20a6f8a39>
> ]
> E:\projects\lambda_test\main.cpp(12): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::function<void (void)>::functionmain::<lambda_a0044794c0b7998ff7e3f3c20a6f8a39,0>(_Fx)' being compiled
> with
> [
> _Fx=main::<lambda_a0044794c0b7998ff7e3f3c20a6f8a39>
> ]
> E:\projects\lambda_test\main.cpp(12): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::function<void (void)>::functionmain::<lambda_a0044794c0b7998ff7e3f3c20a6f8a39,0>(_Fx)' being compiled
> with
> [
> _Fx=main::<lambda_a0044794c0b7998ff7e3f3c20a6f8a39>
> ]

Comment: @user207200 стандарт 17, Вы мне привели ссылку на вопрос как то делать на 11

Comment: Да, понял, у вас проблема вообще не там. Как вариант, `invoke` сделать шаблоном `invoke(T&& act)`.

Comment: Передаваемый в std::function вызываемый объект должен быть CopyConstructible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::function` - копируемый, и требует того же от любого объекта, который в него кладут.

Причем неважно, копируете ли вы на самом деле этот `std::function`, потому что в общем случае это нельзя проверить во время компиляции.

В C++23 будет [`std::move_only_function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/move_only_function), который можно только перемещать, и который не требует копируемости от объектов (а только перемещаемости).

Пока ждете C++23, можно сделать вот так: `invoke(std::ref(lambda));` - это передает не копию лямбды, а ссылку на нее. Поэтому лямбда должна оставаться живой, пока вы пользуетесь этим `std::function`.

Ну или просто не захватывать некопируемые объекты.